# Add subtitle into video using python

Tags: python

I try to add subtitle into video using python. subtitle.srt contains the subtitles of the video. I want to add this into video. I use assembly ai for create subtitle.

```
import assemblyai as aai
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, TextClip, CompositeVideoClip
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import SubtitlesClip

# Set your AssemblyAI API key
aai.settings.api_key = "Api Key"

# Transcribe audio file using AssemblyAI
transcript = aai.Transcriber().transcribe("M:/connection test/VideoSenderReceiver/audio/output_audio.mp3")

# Export subtitles in SRT format
subtitles_srt = transcript.export_subtitles_srt(chars_per_caption=100)

# Write subtitles to a file
with open("M:/connection test/VideoSenderReceiver/subtitlesrt/subtitle.srt", "w") as f:
    f.write(subtitles_srt)
print("Subtitle file created.")

# Load video clip
video_clip = VideoFileClip("M:/connection test/VideoSenderReceiver/videoaudio/fish.mp4")

# Load subtitles from SRT file
subtitles_clip = SubtitlesClip("M:/connection test/VideoSenderReceiver/subtitlesrt/subtitle.srt")

# Create TextClip objects for each subtitle
text_clips = [TextClip(txt, fontsize=24, color='white').set_position('bottom') for (txt, _) in subtitles_clip]

# Composite the text clips onto the video
final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([video_clip.set_duration(subtitles_clip.duration), *text_clips])

# Write the final video with subtitles
final_clip.write_videofile("M:/connection test/VideoSenderReceiver/finalVideo/finalfish.mp4", codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac')
print("Video with subtitles created.")
```

clear this error

```
Subtitle file created.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\connection test\VideoSenderReceiver\.venv\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1094, in __init__
    os.write(temptxt_fd, bytes(txt, 'UTF8'))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: encoding without a string argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
```